# Increment and decrement counter according to select or unselect tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with the next js to handle a question form, I have multiple questions that have multiple answers, and the user may select one or multiple tags for a question.
if a user selects one or more `tag` to answer a question it must `increment` the `counter` just one time, If a user unselect a `tag` it must not `decrement` until unselect the last tag of the related question.

1 - When the user selects a tag of a question at first increment the counter, but it must not increment when I select the second tag in the same question.

2 - When the user unselects tags of question it must not decrement if any one of them is selected it must not decrement until the last one is unselected.

Now when selecting the first tag it increments the counter but after that, if I select or unselect, it does not decrement or increment.

Please help me to handle this.

[image]

**My code:**

```
<TageQuestion
     key={item.attributes.Number}
     id={item.attributes.Number}
     data={item}
     name={`${item.attributes.Number}`}
     errors={errors}
     touched={touched}
     handleSelectOption={handleSelectOption}
/>
```

**The component:**

```
<div className="mt-3">
     {Object.keys(attributes.options).map(item => (
       <div className="inline" key={item}>
         <input
           {...feild}
           {...props}
           className="hidden"
           id={item}
           value={item}
           type="checkbox"
           name={`${name}[answer]`}
         />
         <label
           htmlFor={item}
           id={item + "lable"}
           onClick={e => {
             selectTage(e.target);
             handleSelectOption(`question${id}`, item);
           }}
           className="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 mr-3 mb-2 cursor-pointer"
         >
           {item}
         </label>
       </div>
     ))}
   </div>
```

**The function:**

```
function handleSelectOption(title, item) {
     setCompareTagTitle(title);

     if (title !== compareTagTitle) {
       setTagItem([...tagItem, item]);
       setCounter(++counter);
     } else if (title === compareTagTitle) {
       setCounter(counter);
     } else {
       setCounter(--counter);
     }
}
```

Data that come from the backend:
[image: t,]

Comment: I think you need one another state to set true when for the first time user select and answer then check if already select don't increment the counter.

Comment: I tried, but not solved my problem, may be I did wrong, if it is possible write your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we should consider 2 steps first in child component `TagQuestions` then in parent component `[type].js`

step1:

```
//TagQuestions.js
const [intialRender, setIntialRender] = useState(true);
// if component render for first time
const selectTag = (e) => {
// we should change intialRender to false to say that user select somthing
....
   if (tage.length > 0) {
  const isExit = tage.filter((item) => item.name === el.innerHTML);
  if (isExit.length === 0) {
    setTage([...tage, { name: el.innerHTML }]);
    if (intialRender) {
      setIntialRender(false);
    }
  }
} else {
  setTage([...tage, { name: el.innerHTML }]);
  if (intialRender) {
    setIntialRender(false);
  }
}
....
}
//use effect function to if user unselect all tags after selctions
useEffect(() => {
if (tage.length === 0 && !intialRender) {
   //call parent function and set empty param to true.
   handleSelectOption(`question${id}`, "", true);
 }
}, [tage]);
```

step2(parent component):

```
const [compareTagTitle, setCompareTagTitle] = useState([]);
 function handleSelectOption(title, item, empty = false) {
if (empty) {
      const filter = compareTagTitle.filter(
    (value) => value.toString() !== title.toString()
  )
  setCompareTagTitle(filter);
  setCounter(--counter);
} else {
  if (!compareTagTitle.includes(title)) {
    setCompareTagTitle([...compareTagTitle, title]);
    setCounter(++counter);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I should remove the title from compareTagTitle according to the title because maybe we have more than one component so I should update my answer.

Comment: yes, we have more than one component.

Comment: Now, it works for more than one component.

Comment: your code for multi tag is not working correctly.
1 - when I select a tag for first answer it is ok.
2 - when I select 2 tag for second answer it is ok.
if unselect the first question in number 1 it is okay, but then if I unselect one of the 2 selected tag from question number 2, it increment.

Comment: yes, I did not send the id of component while empty I have updated my code and also filter should be not equal,overall it had 2 bugs and I have updated my code.

Comment: Thnk you bro!  You solved my problem.